# How to find the latest record in cakephp?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I've got a a table with a column request_time. There will be multiple requests and I want to get the latest request of a particular username:

```
$this->Requests->find('all', 'conditions' => array (
                                               'username' => $username, 
                                               'MAX'=> 'request_time'));
```

The above doesn't work.  Is there something in Cakephp or do I need to do my own ->query()?

Comment: do you have auto-incremented primary key ?

Comment: This more about time based queries, but I can see how ID can be used.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
$this->Requests->find('first', array('conditions' => array('username' => $username), 
                               'order' => array('id' => 'DESC') ));
```

Where `id` is the auto incremented primary key.
This will give you the latest (single) record, if you are using `first` in find method, or else use `all` instead.

If you are not using primary key, you can try the following:

```
$this->Requests->find('first', array('conditions' => array('username' => $username), 
                               'order' => array('request_time' => 'DESC') ));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have auto-incremented primary key then you find the latest record of this table try this

```
$this->Requests->find('find', 'conditions' => array ('username' => $username), 
                              'order' => array('id' => 'DESC') 
                      );
```